# phpAES Given final block not properly padded

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I would like to use [phpAES](https://github.com/phillipsdata/phpaes) to encrypt users' passwords with AES256/CBC, transfer the data and decrypt it using different software. In testing used the example provided by the developer and tried decrypting the cypher online at [AES Encryption and Decryption Online Tool](http://%20https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption), unfortunately, I received the following error.

**Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.**

Can anyone provide me with guidance?

Comment: Show your code.  Additionally, you should hash passwords not encrypt them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working with a third party to develop a android app and they requested AES encryption to transfer the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response I received a from the developer.

**The link you provided likely uses a different padding scheme, probably PKCS5. This library currently only supports null byte padding.
Try testing using OFB or CFB modes. More info on block cipher padding can be found here cipher [CryptoSys PKI Pro Manual](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_paddingschemes.html)**

Comment: Did you test as suggested by the dev? This post looks like it should be an *edit* to your original post rather than an answer.